# Check my understanding of proof that Partial order can be extended to total order

Tags: induction, relations, order-theory

Induction step : let n be arbitrary natural number, and suppose that every partial order on a set with n elements can be extended to total order. Suppose A has n+1 elements and R is a partial order on A. So there must be $a \in A$ such that a is R-minimum element of A. Let $A'=A-{a}$ and let $R = R \cap (A' \times A')$. R ' is a partial order on A'. By inductive hypothesis, we can let T' be total order on A' such that $R' \subseteq T'$. Now let $T= T' \cup ({a} \times A)$. So T is a total order on A and R is a subset of T

Now

1. Firstly i  thought about why R' is defined in such a way. So i think it is so because they wanted to exclude all " trace of minimal element and its pairs " from R with disturbing partial ordering.
2. I thought on about why they define T as it is. Since T' is total order on A' and we need total order on A. But $A = A' + {a}$, where a is minimal element. So its defined in such a way so as to squeeze minimal element pairs without disturbing total order. But i took example to see whats happening here. I think if we take $T = T' \cup {(a,a)} $ will also do as we need to satisfy reflexive  property. But i am not sure why they have taken T to be otherwise.

Please comment on my points 1,2

Thanks

Comment: I suppose this is only for partial orderings on finite sets, right?

Comment: @amrsa Yes it is

Comment: Your comment on 2 doesn't work, because $T'\cup\{(a,a)\}$ is not total; hence you need $T' \cup \{a\}\times A$, so $a$ is the least element with respect to $T$.

Comment: @amrsa why not ?

Comment: Well, because in $T=T'\cup\{(a,a)\}$, you have that $a$ is isolated; you don't have $aTx$ for all $x \in A$, but just for $x=a$.

Comment: @amrsa Ah i see. Sorry i forgot the definiton of total order here. What about point 1.

Comment: Regarding your first point, they define $R'$ as the restriction of $R$ to $A'$, and they so define $A'$ to be able to apply induction hypothesis. Notice $A'$ has one element less than $A$.

Comment: @amrsa isnot it same as what i wrote in point1

Comment: what do you mean by restriction of R on A'

Comment: As $a$ is minimal, and $A\setminus\{a\}$ has only $n$ elements, hence a total ordering, then it's just a matter of adding $a$ again below the other elements by the total ordering $T'$, which exists by induction hypothesis. The restriction is precisely what was defined: $R$ is a relation on $A$ and $A' \subset A$, so $R'$ is the restriction of $R$ to $A'$ if $R'=R\cap A'^2$, that is, the pairs related by $R$ but in which both elements are in $A'$.

Comment: @amrsa yes i see that. does it mean they are removing all the associations of minimal element (deleted element) from original relation ?

Comment: Why must there be a minimum $a$? What if you consider the set of $n$ points arranged "side-by-side" and so a partial order with no relationship between distinct points. Does this one have a minimal element?